# Azure App Service FTP is not pointing to correct wwwroot Folder

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, ftp, azure-appservice

I'm experiencing very weird issue with Azure App Service FTP. Was able to connect and deploy asp.net core 3.1 app using FTP, after setting up azure devops CI/CD FTP is no more points to website folder.

Here is my ftp folder (FTP Folder has only wwwroot, deleted everything, but website is functioning)
[image: FTP Folder has only wwwroot, deleted everything, but website is functioning]

Here is my app service editor window (App Service Editor shows a lot of files in the same folder and website actually operates from this folder)
[image: App Service Editor shows a lot of files in the same folder and website actually operates from this folder]

Has anyone experienced this issue? I've had this issue before without any CI/CD implementation and had to delete app service and create a new one, but can't do so each time.
Any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: The WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE setting serves your files from a zip. More info in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67995182/how-do-i-access-my-azure-app-service-files-via-ftp-the-wwwroot-directory-is-emp