# How do I access my Azure App Service Files via FTP? The wwwroot directory is empty

Tags: azure, ftp

Using the Deployment Center link on the App Service page navigation in the azure portal, I was able to find my FTP credentials and easily log in with them. However, there are no files in the wwwroot folder except for hostingstart.html.

[image: empty wwwroot]

However, when I use the Azure Console, all my files appear in the wwwroot folder and the hostingstart.html file is not there.

[image: azure console shows files]

I'm not sure if it's relevant but we do have continuous integration setup. I just want to be able to see those files and interact with them.

If I browse into the /LogFiles folder I can confirm that the FTP and Azure Command Line show the same files. So I know I am on the right server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much searching I learned what is going on. If you have the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` setting enabled, your site is served out of a zip file.

The FTP server shows the real folder, whereas the kudu console maps that folder to the contents of the zip file.

[This announcement explains it in a lot of detail.](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84)

Answer (score 0):

Go to kudu and click "Current Docker logs (Download as zip)"

[image]